# jQuery Child is capturing clicks, only want Parent

Tags: jquery, click

Say i have this:

```
<div id="outer">
 <div id="inner">
 </div>
</div>
```

The outer div's dimensions are 500x500, and the inner is 100x100. I'm trying to employ the following:

```
$('#outer').click(function() {
    $('#outer').fadeOut();
});
```

But when you click on the 100x100 area of `#inner`, it still fades out. How to prevent this?

Comment: you mean the child is capturing clicks, and you only want the parent

Comment: Ah, yes, I mistyped that. To both people below, I've revised the title. I want the outer div to catch clicks, but the inner to ignore. If the user clicks the 100x100 `#inner` I want it to stay open, but if you click outside of that, it needs to fade out.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Better not to assign click handlers for the inner elements. In the click function check event target equal to outer. Something like

```
$('#outer').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.id === "outer"){
        $('#outer').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7RZUC/)

Answer (score 28):

I figured out that this code works better, and is not dependent on knowing the element's id or class:

```
$('#outer').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target === this){
        $('#outer').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: You could even go one further and do `$(this).fadeOut();`

Answer (score 5):

Capture clicks on the inner div and stop it from bubbling:

```
$('#inner').click(function(ev) {
  ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

This is in addition to your above "outer" clicker handler.

Comment: I need `#outer` to catch clicks, and the inner to not. The inner div will have links inside of it, so those need to be able to be clicked on without it closing. Once `#outer` is clicked, it should close.

Comment: give us every step that do you want to do..may we can help.

Comment: Ah, I reapplied the above code and it worked this time. Must have mistyped something last time. Thanks everyone.